# Trackpad firmware doesn't update and now stopped working (Lion & MacBook 13" Unibody)

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update, trackpad, macos

I bought an oldish MacBook 13" Unibody (late 2008) and when I got it one of the first things I did was to install Mac OS X Lion.

Everything was working fine, until I applied an update that made the trackpad stop working (it only accepts clicks, no touch is recognized).

This is the "Trackpad Firmware Update" from the automatic updates.

When starting this firmware update a window appears with a status message, 
`Cancel` and `Update` buttons. After clicking the `Update` button, it starts installing, appears to complete, status changes to `Finishing...`, and `Update` button comes back active at some point.

After that I have tried (unsuccessfully):

- downloading and installing the update directly from Apple Support - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3288
- same thing, but using the 'root' account
- leaving the computer on overnight to see if actually "finished" the
  process
- Reset PRAM PVRAM - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379
- Reset SMC - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964
- Hand palm pressing over 30 seconds on the trackpad (read this on
  another thread...?)
- Reinstalling Mac OS X Lion using a DVD
- Indifferent to USB devices being connected or not

I'd be thankful for any ideas to try out.

Comment: I tried applying this patch with Mac OS X Snow Leopard, with little success. Behavior is similar to installing in Lion...

Comment: No one has any ideas on things to try...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up taking it to an apple technician and they fixed it...